# Given a triangle,a similar triangle $ABC$ is drawn where $A$ is a fixed point and $B$ is any point on a given line.Find the locus of $C$.

Tags: analytic-geometry, locus

Given a triangle,a similar triangle $ABC$ is drawn where $A$ is a fixed point and $B$ is any point on a given line.Find the locus of $C.$

I thought over it but there is no concrete method visible to find out the locus of C.

Comment: Is this a compass-and-straightedge construction? Or is it done with equations in a coordinate system?

Comment: @Arthur,no we have to solve it algebrically.

Comment: Where did you find this ?

Answer (score 4):

Assume that $ABC$ is a triangle and $B$ belongs to some line $l$.

Let $D$ be the intersection $\neq B$ between $l$ and the circumcircle of $ABC$.

Let $C'$ be some point on the line $DC$, and $B'\in l$ a point such that $\widehat{B'AC'}=\widehat{BAC}$.

By angle chasing we have that $B'A C'$ is similar to $BAC$, since both $BACD$ and $B'AC'D$ are cyclic quadrilaterals. It follows that the wanted locus is a line.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Let us consider in the complex plane.

We may suppose that $A(\alpha)$ is at $\alpha=i$ and that $B(\beta)$ is on the real axis ($\beta=p$ where $p\in\mathbb R$).

Also, if we set $q=\frac{A'B'}{C'A'},\theta=\angle{C'A'B'}$, then for $C(\gamma)$, we have
$$\gamma-\alpha=q(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)(\beta-\alpha)$$
where we suppose that $\triangle{A'B'C'}$ is given and that $\triangle{ABC}$ is similar to $\triangle{A'B'C'}$.

Then,
$$\begin{align}\gamma &=i+q(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)(p-i)\\&=i+q(p\cos\theta-i\cos\theta+p\sin\theta i+\sin\theta)\\&=(pq\cos\theta+q\sin\theta)+i(1-q\cos\theta+pq\sin\theta)\end{align}$$
So, if we set $\gamma=x+yi$ where $x,y\in\mathbb R$, then we have
$$x=pq\cos\theta+q\sin\theta,\quad y=1-q\cos\theta+pq\sin\theta$$

Eliminating $p$ from these gives
$$(x-q\sin\theta)q\sin\theta=q\cos\theta(y-1+q\cos\theta),$$
i.e.
$$y-(1-q\cos\theta)=\tan\theta\ (x-q\sin\theta).$$

By the way, we can replace $\theta$ with $-\theta$.

Hence, the answer is that the locus of $C$ is two lines :

$$y-(1-q\cos\theta)=\tan\theta\ (x-q\sin\theta),$$
$$y-(1-q\cos(-\theta))=\tan(-\theta)\ (x-q\sin(-\theta)).$$

Comment: The given answer is $4x^2[\frac{p^2}{r^2}(x^2+(y+h)^2)-h^2]=[\frac{p^2-q^2}{r^2}(x^2+(y+h)^2)+x^2+y ^2-h^2]^2$,where $A=(0,-h)$ and $B$ is on the $x$ axis@mathlove

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia: OK, I'll consider again, but can you tell me what $p,q,r$ are?

Comment: Sir these are not specified in the answer.I was also wondering,what are these stand for.Please forgive me,this is what is given in the book @mathlove

Comment: Sir please dont delete this complex number solution.@mathlove

Answer (score 1):

We may assume $A=0\in{\mathbb C}$, $B=b+t\, i$ with $b>0$ and $t\in{\mathbb R}$. On the other hand, let $\triangle(A_*B_*C_*)\subset {\mathbb C}$ be the given sample triangle, and define $c\in{\mathbb C}\setminus{\mathbb R}$ by
$$C_*-A_*= c(B_*-A_*)\ .$$
The locus in question is then parametrized by
$$t\mapsto C(t):=c(b+t\,i)\qquad(-\infty<t<\infty)\ .$$
It is a line through the point $C_0:=c \,b$, and orthogonal to $c$.